# Redirect messages to another handler in Telegram bot(telethon library)

Tags: telegram, telethon

I'm trying to make menu with navigation buttons in my telethon bot, so when 'Back' message is sent I want to be able to invoke message handler responsible for previous menu, for example main menu with command '/start'. Is there any funcion like `bot.redirect` from the code below that would call `main_menu(event)`?

```py
bot = TelegramClient('bot', BOT_API_ID, BOT_API_HASH).start(
    bot_token=BOT_TOKEN)

@bot.on(events.NewMessage(pattern='/start'))
async def main_menu(event):
    buttons = [  
        Button.text("Music"),
        ...          
    ]    
    message = 'You are in main menu'
    await event.respond(message=message, buttons=buttons)
    raise events.StopPropagation

@bot.on(events.NewMessage(pattern='Music'))
async def music(event):
    buttons = [          
        Button.text("Rap"),            
        Button.text("Hip Hop"),
        ...
        Button.text("Back")                    
    ]   
    message = 'Choose what kind of music you want to find'
    await event.respond(message=message, buttons=buttons)
    raise events.StopPropagation

@bot.on(events.NewMessage(pattern='Back'))
async def back(event):       
    prev_menu = get_prev_menu(event.input_chat.user_id) # Teturns '/start' when in 'Music' menu 
    event.text = prev_menu
    bot.redirect(event) # <==========================================
```

Comment: I think that the best way is to have just one event handler then switching between commands using an `if-elif-else` system on the `event.raw_text`, if you want a cleaner looking handler just call from there the functions passing the `event` object.

Comment: @TheKill-996 That implies I need to maintain mappings for all commands with their functions which I already specified in `bot.on` decorator, that's kinda ugly.

Comment: Nothing's stopping you from doing `await main_menu(event)` from within `async def back(event)`. The event text won't correspond, but you can still use `respond`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Telethon is a library to interact with Telegram and not much else. Business logic like this should live inside your code, but nothing is stopping you from having a "stack" of functions (here, `USER_LOC`):

```py
from collections import defaultdict

bot = TelegramClient('bot', BOT_API_ID, BOT_API_HASH).start(
    bot_token=BOT_TOKEN)

# Store user locations {user_id: [menu callback]}
USER_LOC = defaultdict(list)

@bot.on(events.NewMessage(pattern='/start'))
async def main_menu(event):
    buttons = [  
        Button.text("Music"),
        ...          
    ]    
    message = 'You are in main menu'
    await event.respond(message=message, buttons=buttons)
    USER_LOC[event.sender_id].append(main_menu)  # <- push to stack
    raise events.StopPropagation

@bot.on(events.NewMessage(pattern='Music'))
async def music(event):
    buttons = [          
        Button.text("Rap"),            
        Button.text("Hip Hop"),
        ...
        Button.text("Back")                    
    ]   
    message = 'Choose what kind of music you want to find'
    await event.respond(message=message, buttons=buttons)
    USER_LOC[event.sender_id].append(music)  # <- push to stack
    raise events.StopPropagation

@bot.on(events.NewMessage(pattern='Back'))
async def back(event):
    stack = USER_LOC[event.sender_id]
    if not stack:
        return  # empty
    stack.pop()  # ignore second-to-last
    if stack:
        await stack.pop()(event)  # <- pop last pushed callback and call it
```

You can also write decorators to make it nicer if you want to.

Comment: Im not asking to solve my business logic problems, I just want to use already existing tool of mapping requests to handlers.

Comment: There is no such tool that I'm aware of. My code should solve your issue, though.

Comment: Just wanted to say I'm sorry I didn't understand the subject well at the time and didn't accept your answer)